# setOnCameraIdleListener not found android google map cluster

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing

setOnCameraIdleListener() method not found
 in android google map cluster.

I compiled this library:

> dependencies {  compile
>   'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'}

```
public class ClusteringDemoActivity extends MapsActivity {
private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;

@Override
protected void startDemo() {
    getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));


    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, getMap());



   getMap().setOnCameraIdleListener(mClusterManager);
    getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);


    addItems();
}
private void addItems() {


    double lat = 51.5145160;
    double lng = -0.1270060;


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double offset = i / 60d;
        lat = lat + offset;
        lng = lng + offset;
        MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(lat, lng);
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
}
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by  editing my `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an old version of google play services that doesn't contain the implementation of the method **setOnCameraIdleListener** relative to the GoogleMap class model.

So try to upgrade your play services by putting or editing your build.gradle file:

*compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.1'*

Comment: I will suggest that please use the comment for this type of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

**MarkerClustering.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;

public class MarkerClustering implements GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {

    private static final String TAG = MarkerClustering.class.getSimpleName();

    public MarkerClustering(Activity activity, GoogleMap googleMap) {
        try {
            ClusterManager<CustomClusterItem> clusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(activity, googleMap);

            MarkerRenderer markerRenderer = new MarkerRenderer(activity, googleMap, clusterManager, this);
            clusterManager.setRenderer(markerRenderer);

            googleMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(clusterManager);
            googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(clusterManager);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
//        Your code
    }
}
```

**MarkerRenderer.java**

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer;

public class MarkerRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<CustomClusterItem> implements GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {
    private GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener onCameraIdleListener;

    public MarkerRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap googleMap, ClusterManager<CustomClusterItem> clusterManager, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener onCameraIdleListener) {
        super(context, googleMap, clusterManager);
        this.onCameraIdleListener = onCameraIdleListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        if (onCameraIdleListener != null) {
            onCameraIdleListener.onCameraIdle();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use Default ClusterItem. If you want means customize it by custom class like below.

**CustomClusterItem.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterItem;

public class CustomClusterItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng latLng;

    CustomClusterItem(LatLng latLng) {
        this.latLng = latLng;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLng getPosition() {
        return latLng;
    }
}
```